# regionType poperty in Marionette

Tags: javascript, marionette

```
MyApp.addRegions({
  someRegion: {
    selector: "#foo",
    regionType: MyCustomRegion
  })
```

what's regionType in Marionette and how use it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the `regionType` is set to `Marionette.Region`.

But if you want some special functionality from your Region you could create a custom Region.

```
var MyCustomRegion = Marionette.Region.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        console.log("I'm special!");
    }
});
```

You could then use `MyCustomRegion` like in your example:

```
MyApp.addRegions({
    someRegion: {
        selector: "#foo",
        regionType: MyCustomRegion
    })
```